# AddPoint(x,y) Using C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x,y;
}point;

void printPoint( point p )
{

    printf("(%d,%d)",p.x,p.y);
}

point addPoint( point p1, point p2 )
{
    point pResult;
    pResult.x = p1.x + p2.x ;
    pResult.y = p1.y + p2.y ;
    return pResult;
}

int main()
{
    point p1,p2;
    printf("Enter first point: ");
    scanf("%d,%d",p1.x,p1.y);
    printf("Enter second point: ");
    scanf("%d,%d",p2.x,p2.y);
    
}
```

This is an unfinish code which I dont know what to do next ( Homework ). The question need me to add both points together into 1 point but I'm not sure what to do in int main() as the final step.
'point addPoint' is a must-use given from the question (meaning that I can't edit it).Please go easy on me since I'm kinda bad at this part of coding.

Edited : [image] This is what the output supposed to be.

Edit 2 : [image]

This is what I managed to do.

Comment: Call `AddPoint` maybe?

Comment: In coding, it's usually free things out.  It's often an effective way to learn, too.

Comment: Scanf needs addresses to fill memory : `scanf("%d,%d",&(p1.x),&(p1.y));`

Comment: Ohhhh I forgot about the & Thanks you. Now I will try the one I just think of if it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this would do:

```
point p3 = addPoint(p1, p2);
printPoint(p1);
printf(" + ");
printPoint(p2);
printf(" = "):
printPoint(p3)
```

Comment: @DavidRanieri I left the print part out as op only asked about adding, and if op literally needs what the image shows it would be `printPoint(p1); printf(" + "); printPoint(p2); printf(" = "): printPoint(p3)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! but can I ask about why I can't use printPoint(pResult); or printPoint(addPoint); ?

Comment: `pResult` is a variable in `addPoint()` and you said you could not modify that function, and the variable is not available in `main()`.  You could do `printPoint(addPoint(p1, p2))` but it's usually clearer to introduce a variable in this case `p3`.

Comment: Alright! Thank you.

Comment: Well .. without the print it seems like an incomplete answer, mainly because the compiler will optimize out 
(the result is not used)  the call to addPoint. But feel free to rollback, is your answer :)

Comment: @DavidRanieri Cheers.